# Custom painter painting outside of the screen for new incoming data?

Tags: flutter, dart, waveform, flutter-custompainter

I am implementing waveform visualization for mic in my app.

```
class BarVisualizer extends CustomPainter {
  final List<double> waveData;
BarVisualizer({
    required this.waveData,
});
 @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < waveData.length; i++) {
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(i.toDouble() + i  , 0),
          Offset(i.toDouble() +  i, -waveData[i]), wavePaint);     
    }
  }
@override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
```

above `for-loop` draws lines for each decibel value I get from mic.
As I am using a mic to get data, the list of decibel will get large and it start painting outside of the screen.

So my question is how can I move the previously painted lines back to paint new incoming decibel values inside the screen?

Comment: You need to determine which at which length of the list it starts drawing offscreen and at that point remove first element from `waveData` each time you adding new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did was created a callback when a certain condition matches and call the setState from that call back to the offset which looks like this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < waveData.length; i++) {
if ((spacing * i) + offset.dx > size.width * sizeCounter) {
          callback();
        }
        canvas.drawLine(
            Offset(-scrollOffset.dx + offset.dx + (spacing * i), 100),
            Offset(-scrollOffset.dx + offset.dx + (spacing * i),
                -waveData[i] + 100),
            wavePaint);
      }
```

now in the UI,

```
CustomPaint(
     painter: Barpainter(
              callback:(){
                WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
                                  (timeStamp) {
                                setState(
                                      () {
                                    scrollOffset +=  Offset(width, 0);
                                    sizeCounter++;
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            );
       }
  )
)
```

this add extra offset when it reaches end of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Use the `canvas.translate` method to move the canvas surface around, so that your draw calls can always be within the screen bounds.  You will need to also change your `drawLine` calls to accommodate for how the canvas has moved.

Comment: do I use `canvas.translate` like minus some pixel for each new value in that and also from offset in drawline?

Comment: What a great idea, this certainly won't cause any performance issue